# How to define correctly arithmetic operator overloading for user defined complex number in fortran?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

My IDE is: Code::Blocks 20.03 ( MinGW 9.2.0 )

This is my simple code:

```
module mod_kompleks

  use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding, only : rp => c_double

  implicit none

  type, public :: kom_bro

    private

    real(rp) :: dio_rea
    real(rp) :: dio_img

    contains

      procedure, private :: kom_bro_sab    ! 16 line

      generic, public :: operator(+) => kom_bro_sab  ! 18 line

  end type kom_bro

  interface kom_bro

    module procedure :: kom_bro_set

  end interface kom_bro

  contains

  ! procedure - kom_bro_set

    type(kom_bro) function kom_bro_set(rea_part, img_part) result(bro_c)

      real, intent(in) :: rea_part, img_part

      bro_c%dio_rea = rea_part
      bro_c%dio_img = img_part

    end function kom_bro_set

  ! procedure - kom_bro_sab

    function kom_bro_sab(bro_a, bro_b) result(bro_c)

      type(kom_bro), intent(in) :: bro_a
      type(kom_bro), intent(in) :: bro_b
      type(kom_bro)             :: bro_c

      bro_c%dio_rea = bro_a%dio_rea + bro_b%dio_rea
      bro_c%dio_img = bro_a%dio_img + bro_b%dio_img

    end function kom_bro_sab

end module mod_kompleks

program kompleksni_broj

  use, non_intrinsic :: mod_kompleks

  implicit none

  integer :: i

  type(kom_bro) :: broj_01(3)
  type(kom_bro) :: broj_02(3)
  type(kom_bro) :: broj_03(3)

  do i = 1, 3

    broj_01(i) = kom_bro(i + 2.2,i + 3.3)
    broj_02(i) = kom_bro(i + 4.4,i + 5.5)

    broj_03(i) = broj_01(i) + broj_02(i)

  end do

end program kompleksni_broj
```

I intend to define a user type that would look like a complex number but would also allow the arithmetic operation of adding two complex numbers. Since I am not experienced in the programming language Fortran in my example I came across a problem where the compiler reports the following errors to me:

`|16|Error: Non-polymorphic passed-object dummy argument of 'kom_bro_sab'`
`|18|Error: Undefined specific binding 'kom_bro_sab' as target of GENERIC '+'`
`||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|`

My knowledge of OOP in the programming language Fortran is not enough for me to be able to solve this problem on my own.
Is it even possible to define such a user-defined type?

Comment: The errors you report aren't the only errors a compiler will find in the code above - could you either post the full list of errors, or the code you are actually compiling.

Comment: @IanBush These are the only two errors that the compiler displays.

Comment: "the procedure, private :: kom_bro_sab    ! 16 line" is not Fortran. What should it be?

Comment: @IanBush Now is Fortran. I do not know how that part was inserted there. Maybe that part got there while writing the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple errors. Most important the operator overloading is wrong. See my example implementation below.

Derived data type for complex numbers (file name `b.f90`)

```pascal
module mod_kompleks
  use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding, only : rp => c_double
  implicit none

  private
  public kom_bro
  public operator(+)

  type kom_bro
    private
    real(rp) :: dio_rea
    real(rp) :: dio_img
  contains
    procedure :: init  => kom_bro_init
    procedure :: print => kom_bro_print
  end type

  interface operator(+)
    module procedure kom_bro_sab
  end interface

  interface kom_bro
    module procedure kom_bro_init2
  end interface
contains
  function kom_bro_init2(rea_part, img_part) result(bro)
    real(rp), intent(in) :: rea_part
    real(rp), intent(in) :: img_part
    type(kom_bro)        :: bro

    call bro%init(rea_part, img_part)
  end function

  subroutine kom_bro_init(this, rea_part, img_part)
    class(kom_bro), intent(out) :: this
    real(rp),       intent(in)  :: rea_part
    real(rp),       intent(in)  :: img_part

    this%dio_rea = rea_part
    this%dio_img = img_part
  end subroutine

  subroutine kom_bro_print(this)
    class(kom_bro), intent(in) :: this

    print *, this%dio_rea, this%dio_img
  end subroutine

  function kom_bro_sab(bro_a, bro_b) result(bro_c)
    type(kom_bro), intent(in) :: bro_a
    type(kom_bro), intent(in) :: bro_b
    type(kom_bro)             :: bro_c

    bro_c%dio_rea = bro_a%dio_rea + bro_b%dio_rea
    bro_c%dio_img = bro_a%dio_img + bro_b%dio_img
  end function
end module
```

Program (file name `a.f90`)

```pascal
program kompleksni_broj
  use mod_kompleks
  use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding, only : rp => c_double

  implicit none

  integer       :: i
  type(kom_bro) :: broj_01(3), broj_02(3), broj_03(3)

  do i = 1, 3
    call broj_01(i)%init(i + 2.2_rp, i + 3.3_rp)      ! initialization via type-bound routine
    broj_02(i) = kom_bro(i + 4.4_rp, i + 5.5_rp)      ! initialization via interface kom_bro aka "type constructor"

    broj_03(i) = broj_01(i) + broj_02(i)
    call broj_03(i)%print()
  end do

end program
```

Output

```sh
$ gfortran -g3 -Wall -fcheck=all b.f90 a.f90 && ./a.out
   3.2000000000000002        5.4000000000000004        8.6000000000000014     
   4.2000000000000002        6.4000000000000004        10.600000000000001     
   5.2000000000000002        7.4000000000000004        12.600000000000001
```

Comment: You can do the operator overloading via a generic type bound procedure, in fact I had a working example before I started totally rearranging Christmas due to the Glorious Leader's belated pronouncements this afternoon - lost the will to live now, will post tomorrow.

Comment: The solution is great and revealed many things to me. Can you show me how this is done in a way that uses `generic, public :: operator (+)`?Is it possible to create a function constructor named `kom_bro` if` bro_rea` and `bro_img` with the attribute are private?

Comment: @IanBush I will really appreciate your move if you show the way through a generic name tomorrow because I want to learn how to do it through a generic name and how to do it through an interface operator. Is it possible to create a function constructor named kom_bro if` bro_rea` and bro_img with the attribute are private?

Comment: @HarryKastorp I added code to the example solution. I hope it answers your question on: _"Is it possible to create a function constructor named kom_bro if` bro_rea` and bro_img with the attribute are private?"_

Comment: @HarryKastorp You would need to rename the constuctor interface. Otherwise you cannot differentiate between them in a `use mod_kompleks, only: kom_bro` statement. Standard method is to use the type-bound `init` routine anyways.

Comment: @IanBush I saw your answer briefly during the night, but now it's gone.

Comment: @HarryKastorp I think it is appropriate to create a new question for the _visibility_ question. there is no benefit of discussing it here in the comments (actually we should be deleting those comments as they are not connected to the overloading of operators).

Comment: @HarryKastorp - posted it then deleted it as without explanation I thought it inappropriate. Been too busy with other stuff today. Will get back to it at some point.

Comment: @HarryKastorp undeleted my previous answer, not really in a position to polish it as I had hoped

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code I wrote which is a bit of a mess, but shows what I think you are after

```
ian@eris:~/work/stack$ gfortran --version
GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

ian@eris:~/work/stack$ cat poly.f90
module mod_kompleks

  use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding, only : rp => c_double

  implicit none

  type, public :: kom_bro

    private

    real(rp) :: dio_rea
    real(rp) :: dio_img

    contains

      Procedure, private :: kom_bro_sab    ! 16 line
      Procedure, Public  :: print => kom_bro_print
      Procedure, Public  :: set   => kom_bro_set

      generic, public :: operator(+) => kom_bro_sab  ! 18 line

  end type kom_bro

!!$  interface kom_bro
!!$
!!$    module procedure :: kom_bro_set
!!$
!!$  end interface kom_bro

  Private

contains

  ! procedure - kom_bro_set

!!$    type(kom_bro) function kom_bro_set(rea_part, img_part) result(bro_c)
    Subroutine kom_bro_set( bro_c, rea_part, img_part)

      Class( kom_bro ), Intent( InOut ) :: bro_c

      real, intent(in) :: rea_part, img_part

      bro_c%dio_rea = rea_part
      bro_c%dio_img = img_part

!!$    end function kom_bro_set
    end Subroutine kom_bro_set

  ! procedure - kom_bro_sab

    function kom_bro_sab(bro_a, bro_b) result(bro_c)

      Class(kom_bro), intent(in) :: bro_a
      Class(kom_bro), intent(in) :: bro_b
      Class(kom_bro), Allocatable :: bro_c

      ! Allocate the return value to the same type as
      ! one of the provided arguments - may have to modify this depending
      ! on requirements
      Allocate( bro_c, Mold = bro_a )
      
      bro_c%dio_rea = bro_a%dio_rea + bro_b%dio_rea
      bro_c%dio_img = bro_a%dio_img + bro_b%dio_img

    end function kom_bro_sab

    Subroutine kom_bro_print( bro_a )

      Class( kom_bro ), Intent( In ) :: bro_a

      Write( *, * ) 'Real: ', bro_a%dio_rea, ' Imag: ', bro_a%dio_img
      
    End Subroutine kom_bro_print

end module mod_kompleks

program kompleksni_broj

  use, non_intrinsic :: mod_kompleks

  implicit none

  integer :: i

  type(kom_bro) :: broj_01(5)
  type(kom_bro) :: broj_02(5)
  type(kom_bro) :: broj_03(5)

  do i = 1, 5

!!$    broj_01(i) = kom_bro(i + 2.2,i + 3.3)
!!$    broj_02(i) = kom_bro(i + 4.4,i + 5.5)
     Call broj_01(i)%set(i + 2.2,i + 3.3)
     Call broj_02(i)%set(i + 4.4,i + 5.5)
     
    broj_03(i) = broj_01(i) + broj_02(i)

    Write( *, * ) i
    Call broj_01(i)%print
    Write( *, * ) i
    Call broj_02(i)%print
    Write( *, * ) i
    Call broj_03(i)%print

    Write( *, * )
    
  end do

end program kompleksni_broj
ian@eris:~/work/stack$ gfortran -std=f2008 -Wall -Wextra -fcheck=all poly.f90 
ian@eris:~/work/stack$ ./a.out
           1
 Real:    3.2000000476837158       Imag:    4.3000001907348633     
           1
 Real:    5.4000000953674316       Imag:    6.5000000000000000     
           1
 Real:    8.6000001430511475       Imag:    10.800000190734863     

           2
 Real:    4.1999998092651367       Imag:    5.3000001907348633     
           2
 Real:    6.4000000953674316       Imag:    7.5000000000000000     
           2
 Real:    10.599999904632568       Imag:    12.800000190734863     

           3
 Real:    5.1999998092651367       Imag:    6.3000001907348633     
           3
 Real:    7.4000000953674316       Imag:    8.5000000000000000     
           3
 Real:    12.599999904632568       Imag:    14.800000190734863     

           4
 Real:    6.1999998092651367       Imag:    7.3000001907348633     
           4
 Real:    8.3999996185302734       Imag:    9.5000000000000000     
           4
 Real:    14.599999427795410       Imag:    16.800000190734863     

           5
 Real:    7.1999998092651367       Imag:    8.3000001907348633     
           5
 Real:    9.3999996185302734       Imag:    10.500000000000000     
           5
 Real:    16.599999427795410       Imag:    18.800000190734863     

ian@eris:~/work/stack$
```